# How to use a controller's array in js.erb without converting array to a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

**home_controller.rb**

```
    class HomeController < ApplicationController
      def index
        @labels = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'].to_json.html_safe
      end
    end
```

**_main.js.erb**

```
window.onload = function() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('fgm').getContext('2d');
    console.log("<%= escape_javascript @labels %>");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: "<%= escape_javascript @labels %>",
```

**browser console log**

```
["Red","Blue","Yellow","Green","Purple","Orange"]
```

**browser debugging**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('fgm').getContext('2d');
    console.log("[\"Red\",\"Blue\",\"Yellow\",\"Green\",\"Purple\",\"Orange\"]");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: "[\"Red\",\"Blue\",\"Yellow\",\"Green\",\"Purple\",\"Orange\"]",
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
```

This line is my problem:

```
        labels: "[\"Red\",\"Blue\",\"Yellow\",\"Green\",\"Purple\",\"Orange\"]",
```

as I need it to not be encased in quotes e.g.

```
        labels: ["Red","Blue","Yellow","Green","Purple","Orange"],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
@labels = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'].to_json.html_safe
```

And use it like this, with no surrounding `"` and you don't need to escape it (it's already scaped with to_json and html_safe):

```
console.log(<%= @labels %>);
labels: <%= @labels %>,
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work

**home_controller.rb**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @labels = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange']
    # You don't need to use to_json and html_safe
  end
end
```

**_main.js.erb**

```
window.onload = function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('fgm').getContext('2d');
  labels = <%= raw @labels %> # use raw method
  console.log(labels);
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
```

Comment: This works for my simple example above, but in my app I am returning an array of dates which returns `console.log([Sun, 03 Nov 2019, Mon, 04 Nov 2019, Tue, 05 Nov 2019, Wed, 06 Nov 2019]);` and throws an `Uncaught SyntaxError; Unexpected identifier error`